# How can I keep docker container alive long enough for New Relic send traced exceptions?

Tags: php, docker, newrelic

We are running a php cli command in a docker container with New Relic deamon installed to track exceptions. The problem is that New Relic sends exception traces on an [interval of 1 minute](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/errors-dont-get-send-after-php-process-in-docker-container-crashes-due-to-exception/46372/2?u=jeroen3), but when our php process crashes due to an exception, the container gets killed right away.

Is there a (simple) solution to keep the container alive for about one minute after the php process has died, for example by wrapping it in some other script/program?

Comment: append at the end of you CMD or ENTRRYPOINT `; sleep 120`?

Comment: We tried that, but it can't find the command that way: "Could not open input file: bin/console; sleep 10"

Comment: Post a reproducer, the Dockerfile and the docker run command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of user2915097, which got me thinking, we've found a solution. We wrote a small script which we use an entrypoint of the container and sleep when the script fails.

cron-php-entrypoint:

```
#!/bin/sh

eval "$@" || (echo 'Delaying exit for 60 seconds for New Relic to send its report...' && sleep 60)
```

Lines to add to Dockerfile:

```
COPY cron-php-entrypoint /usr/local/bin/

ENTRYPOINT ["cron-php-entrypoint"]
```